This error " Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] " when i try to signIn with jwt nodejs
module.exports.singIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body

  try {
    const user = await UserModel.login(email, password)
    const token = createToken(user._id)
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, maxAge });
    res.status(200).json({ user: user._id })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(200).json({ error });
  }
}

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
at Route. [as post] (/home/cedrick/Documents/formation-mastering-front-end/fullstack/soko/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:216:15)
at proto. [as post] (/home/cedrick/Documents/formation-mastering-front-end/fullstack/soko/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:521:19)
at Object. (/home/cedrick/Documents/formation-mastering-front-end/fullstack/soko/api/routes/user.route.js:8:8)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
at Object. (/home/cedrick/Documents/formation-mastering-front-end/fullstack/soko/api/server.js:4:20)

signIn is a property, so when using it, do it like so:
const {signIn} = require('./signin');

app.use('/signin', signIn, ...

or, remove signIn when exporting to load it as a function:
// signin.js
module.exports = exports = async (req, res) => {...

//app
const signIn = require('./signin');

app.use('/signin', signIn, ...

Modules: CommonJS modules
